# Escaping spaces with backslash

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, variable

Not much context to it.

```
export essential='/Users/mac/Desktop/AP\ Prep/javatest/essentials'

cd "$essential"
```

Yields this error:

```
-bash: cd: /Users/mac/Desktop/AP\ Prep/javatest/essentials: No such file or directory
```

The cd command is correct :

```
cd /Users/mac/Desktop/AP\ Prep/javatest/essentials works.
```

It looks fine ...I've tried it with double quotes and no quotes as well.
Help please???

Comment: don't use backslashes as scape char inside single quotes; you don't need to scape spaces inside single quotes.

Comment: The bash manual tells you what double quotes to: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes -- also read the section just above that about single quotes.